# accumulate not working in Scheme Lang R5RS

Tags: scheme

I solved a problem which involved using `map` and `accumulate` but it gave me this error: `"accumulate: undefined;" cannot reference undefined identifier.`

This is my code:

```
;Procedure to test it with
(define (double x)
   (* 2 x))

(define (my-map proc sequence) 
   (accumulate (lambda (x y) (cons (proc x) y)) '() sequence))
```

Please can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The procedure `accumulate` is not defined in R5RS. But it's simple enough to define your own:

```
(define (accumulate proc init lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      init
      (proc (car lst)
            (accumulate proc init (cdr lst)))))
```

For future reference, `accumulate` is also known as `foldr`, `fold-right`, `inject` or `reduce` in other programming languages, consult your interpreter's [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) for more details.